# Error adding current class to li

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add current class to `li` of navigation tab. Following is my code

```
<nav class="tabs-nav quickset-tabs">
    <ul class="hidden" data-bind="css: { hidden: false }, foreach: currentTab().subMenus">
        <li class="" data-bind="visible: visible"><a data-bind="click: $parent.openTab, text: title"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

jQuery code as follows

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('ul li a').click(function() {
        $('ul li.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
    });

</script>
```

I am not able to find why it is not adding `current` class to `li` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a function and called it onclick of button and it worked. Following is the code

```
<script async="async"> $('.resident-admin-tabs ul li').click(function () { $('.quickset-tabs ul .litab:first-child').addClass('current'); }); function ActiveTab(evt) { $('.litab').removeClass('current'); console.log(evt); $(evt).addClass('current') }; </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the click handler is added at page load, and any `a` elements added dynamically won't have it applied.  See the code below for a working solution that will apply the click handler to newly-added elements as well.  (For demonstration purposes, any element with the `current` class will be highlighted.)  Clicking on the anchor applies the class to the list item.

```js
$('ul li a').click(function() {
        $('ul li.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
    });

var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
function addAnchor() {    // add another anchor element
  list.innerHTML = $('ul').html() + '<li class="" data-bind="visible: visible"><a data-bind="    click: $parent.openTab, text: title">Anchor</a>List item</li>';
  $('ul li a').unbind();
  $('ul li a').click(function() {
        $('ul li.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
    });
}
```

```css
a {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.current {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="tabs-nav quickset-tabs">
                <ul class="hidden" data-bind="css: { hidden: false }, foreach: currentTab().subMenus">
                    <li class="" data-bind="visible: visible"><a data-bind="    click: $parent.openTab, text: title">Anchor</a>List item</li>
                </ul>
                </nav>
                
<button onclick="addAnchor();">Add An Anchor</button>
```

This is the relevant part of the code that adds the click handler to each new `a` element:

```
  $('ul li a').unbind();
  $('ul li a').click(function() {
        $('ul li.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, anchor tag's text generates dynamically and yes problem is with something else this function is not calling on anchor tag click don't know why.

Comment: @C.jacking Can you include your code that generates the anchor tag then? Might be a problem there. As it stands right now, when you click on the anchor tag, it adds that class.

Comment: There is a whole lot of knockoutjs code for that but it is creating correct anchor tag "<a data-bind=" click: $parent.openTab, text: title">Manage Account</a>" here is the sample

Comment: @C.jacking See my edited answer above. Your problem was that new `a` elements weren't getting the click handler added. This code adds the handler to new elements.

Comment: thanks for you reply, i don't know why but my click is not calling this function i have script on site.master and tried put it in user control of that same tab menu but still not able to call that function.

Comment: @C.jacking Are you clicking on the "Anchor" part (rather than the "List Item" part)?

Comment: Does it work for you when you do it here, on this page, by clicking "Run code snippet" and clicking on an anchor tag?

Comment: In your JavaScript file, add an `alert('check 1');` line somewhere in the body (not inside a function) and an `alert('check 2');` inside the `$('ul li a').click(function() {` function... Does the first alert get triggered on page load, and does the second alert get triggered when you click on the anchor?

Comment: I did that, outside alert calls when page loads but inner alert does not call on anchor click. but it is working fine in "Run code snippet". I don't know what is wrong with this issue.

Comment: I have got something  $('ul li a').click(function () {
            //$('ul li.current').removeClass('current');
            //$(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
          
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".litab a").click(function () {
                  
                    $('.litab').removeClass('current');
                    $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');

                });
            }, 2000); It is working, But it doen not work when i click another parent tab and come back to child tab and click one of them.

Comment: @C.jacking Clicking another parent tab and coming back shouldn't affect this function, as it doesn't depend on focus or being the active element.  Can you start a new question, maybe with a larger section of your code, and we can take a look at it?

Comment: Thanks @freginold for your continuous support. I have created a function and called it onclick of button and it worked. Following is the function   <script async="async">
        $('.resident-admin-tabs ul li').click(function () {
            $('.quickset-tabs ul .litab:first-child').addClass('current');
        });
       function ActiveTab(evt) {
                    $('.litab').removeClass('current');   
                    console.log(evt);
                    $(evt).addClass('current')
        };


    </script>